# Android spinner popup dropdown position and size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-spinner

I managed to change the Spinner background and it's popup dropdown background. I can adjust the popup `android:dropDownHorizontalOffset` and `android:dropDownVerticalOffset`.
I also have a custom layout for the spinner items.

But, i am stuck with this look:

[image]

Notice how the items are outside the boundries of the popup dropdown. How can I fix that? Is there a way to insert padding for the top and bottom of the items somehow?

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/branchesSpinner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dropdown_base"
        android:dropDownHorizontalOffset="-5dp"
        android:dropDownVerticalOffset="50dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:popupBackground="@drawable/rounded_rectangle_4"
         />
```

---

spinner_item_custom_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/charcoal"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:text="Select Branch"></TextView>
```

N.B: The backgrounds I added are .PNG images and not XML

Comment: Are you using a custom background for your spinner by using `android:popupBackground`?

Comment: @SonTruong yes i am

Comment: Please post the custom background as well.

Comment: @SonTruong I updated the question with the Spinner XML

Comment: Can you add `rounded_rectangle_4.xml`?

Comment: @SonTruong It is just a png image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182472/discussion-between-son-truong-and-mena).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using a png file as popup background for the spinner so there are 2 limitations

- If you run the app on devices which have high screen density, your spinner background might be stretch and look so ugly.
- You cannot set padding for you popup background, that why sometimes your content is not looking good as you expected.

**Solution:** Using 9-patch images. You can take a look a guide from Android official site about how to use [draw9patch](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch)

I've just used `draw9patch` tool to edit your `rounded_rectangle_4.png`.

[image: rounded_rectangle_4.9.png]

You can replace with your current background then give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create custom adapter for your spinner.
Then, in getDropDownView method of the adapter class you need to set top margin of the dropdown item when the position is 0 using below code

```
public static void setMargins (View v, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
if (v.getLayoutParams() instanceof ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) {
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams p = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
    p.setMargins(l, t, r, b);
    v.requestLayout();
}
```

}

Just make your logic to compare the position of dropdown child.
Note that you need to set only top margin.

Comment: Problem is that the parent of popupDrawable is `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` which doesn't have method `setMargins`.